# Summation Solution differing from Integral Solution

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation

I know this is elementary stuff but I'm hoping to clear get it cleared up.

*I have a money making machine. I turn on the machine and for the first day I make $5.70.*

*For every subsequent day, I make a profit that is $.35 less.*

I want to use basic calculus to find how much I've made in (t) days.

So from what I can see, my profit on a given t(the day, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc) is given by

```
profitPerDay = 5.70 - .35(t)
```

If I want the profit after 3 days I take the following definite integral from t=0, to t=3

```
Integral(t=0, t=3) [5.70 - .35(t)]dt
```

and I get

```
profit(day) = 5.7t - .35t^2 = 14.65
```

But when I simply sum up the 3 profits over each day given by

```
profitPerDay = 5.70 - .35(t)
```

and compare, I get 15.00 instead

```
[5.7 - .35(1)] + [5.7 - .35(2)] + [5.7 - .35(3)]  = 15.00
```

What am I doing wrong in this integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral sums continuously whereas the normal sum is discrete. What you have done is integrated the expression $5.7-.35t$, and approximated the same integral with a Riemann sum. The picture below shows how the approximation works

[image: riemann sums]

Which one to use depends on if your machine is constantly outputting money, or if it only outputs, say, once a day.

Comment: The way the machine is described in the question, it seems that, even if it outputs money continuously, the right answer is given by the sum, not the integral.  The reason is that the question says "for the first day I make 5.70", not that the machine is initially outputting money at a rate of 5.70 per day which could then decrease gradually during the first day.  The numbers in the question are already integrals over $1$-day periods.